# Password reset recovery in GUN

Tags: gun

I look at the SEA API as well as the Gun User Management module, but could not find any provision for recovering or resetting user password. there would be instances where the recall flag would not be set to true. how does one go about this in the event that a user forgot their password (on the web )

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible.

Here is a video of it working in action:
https://d.tube/#!/v/marknadal/gfqglxvd

Here is some code that helps:
https://gist.github.com/amark/755193244d28f4f4c980130055a26e5c